# Media queries not working (Zurb Foundation)

Tags: css, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I recently started using Zurb Foundation and am trying to use media queries in order to modify a certain .css class, but can't get it working. 
Below are the (as far as I know) relevant parts of the .scss files.

```
// d. Media Query Ranges
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

// $small-range: (0em, 40em);
// $medium-range: (40.063em, 64em);
// $large-range: (64.063em, 90em);
// $xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em);
// $xxlarge-range: (120.063em, 99999999em);

$small-range: (0em, 40em);
$medium-range: (40.063em, 64em);
$large-range: (64.063em, 90em);
$xlarge-range: (90.063em, 120em);
$xxlarge-range: (120.063em, 99999999em);

// $screen: "only screen";

$screen: "only screen";

// $landscape: "#{$screen} and (orientation: landscape)";
// $portrait: "#{$screen} and (orientation: portrait)";

// $small-up: $screen;
// $small-only: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)})";

$small-up: $screen;
$small-only: "#{$screen} and (max-width: #{upper-bound($small-range)})";

// $medium-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)})";
// $medium-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})";

$medium-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)})";
$medium-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($medium-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($medium-range)})";


// $large-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)})";
// $large-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-range)})";

$large-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)})";
$large-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($large-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($large-range)})";

// $xlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)})";
// $xlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xlarge-range)})";

// $xxlarge-up: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)})";
// $xxlarge-only: "#{$screen} and (min-width:#{lower-bound($xxlarge-range)}) and (max-width:#{upper-bound($xxlarge-range)})";

// Legacy
// $small: $medium-up;
// $medium: $medium-up;
// $large: $large-up;

$small: $medium-up;
$medium: $medium-up;
$large: $large-up;
```

---

```
@import "settings";
@import "foundation";


@media #{small-up} {
    .blok {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #000000;
        margin: 0 5px 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 100%; 
    }
}

@media #{large-up} {
    .blok {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: $primary-color;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Thanks in advance,

Jasper

Comment: What exactly isnt working? If you inspect do you see the queries loaded in at all?

Comment: Hi, the media queries are not showing at all.

It works when changing the CSS into, but I would like to do it "the Foundation way":
`@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
 .blok {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 100%;
 }
}`

Comment: Did you launch `grunt build` after ?

Comment: Yes, grunt is running in watch mode and compiling the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media #{small-up} {
```

needs to be

```
@media #{$small-up} {
```

As $small-up is the variable you're trying to access which is set in the settings file.

Comment: So easy... Thanks!
The $ must have disappeared while copying and pasting..:(